# Swift: Problems with custom UIView.transition?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

Ok, I have looked through https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/ and SO questions similarly trying to make custom transitions with a tab bar controller and its viewcontrollers but Im running into confusion after figuring out the main steps here.

I need to know how (meaning example code would be really helpful) to call a custom `UIView.transition` OR just have a custom `option` in `UIView.transition`. I need to use this to make a sliding/modal -mimicking transition between tabs in my tab bar controller.

The only way I can get a transition to happen is using the below function (this makes them dissolve):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

            if selectedViewController == nil || viewController == selectedViewController {
                return false
            }

            let fromView = selectedViewController!.view
            let toView = viewController.view

            UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)

            return true
        }
```

And calling it manually here where I programmatically chnage the `*selectedIndex*` for my tab controller:

```
//SWITCHES BUTTON -------------------------------------------
    func switchTab(index: Int)

    {
        //transition
        self.tabBarController(self, shouldSelect: (viewControllers?[index])!)
```

I have read about and tried making a custom class `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` but don't know how this would fit in programmatically here -

my attempts passing my tab bar controller and the `toView` and `fromView`into the custom class result in nothing happening/animating. That is why Ive resorted to UIView.transition here.

How can I make a custom `UIView.transition`? What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should conform to UITabBarControllerDelegate
and Create a customTransition class and pass it as follows:

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = TabAnimationManager()
        return    animator

    }
```

And Class TabAnimationManager should be a subclass of UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition and conform UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol. You can add your custom animations in that class.