# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning only works every other time?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, transition

I have been at this for hours and cant understand what i am doing wrong. I have rigged up custom tab bar controller transitions by conforming to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` as described in my previous [Swift: Problems with custom UIView.transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929116/swift-problems-with-custom-uiview-transition/45929810#45929810)

I don't use the normal storyboard tab bar buttons, I switch selectedIndex programmatically. My problem is that only with this implemented:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = ModalTransition()
        animator.fromView = fromVC.view
        animator.toView = toVC.view
        return  animator

    }
```

the animations AND switching of index occurs only every other time. I have custom buttons to switch the index and every other time, nothing happens when I click the switch button. Here is my animation:

```
//
//  ModalTransition.swift
//  Adventures In Design
//
//  Created by Skylar Thomas on 8/28/17.
//

import UIKit

class ModalTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    weak var transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?
    var fromView = UIView()
    var toView = UIView()
    var duration = 1.1


    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        containerView.addSubview(toView)
        containerView.sendSubview(toBack: toView)

        print("ANIMATING")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.fromView.center.y += 900

        }, completion: {
            finished in

            //only works every OTHER click
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            self.fromView.center.y -= 900
        })


    }
}
```

What is causing this? Is it something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not assigning your toView and FromView. Try something like this

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!

    let fromView = fromViewController.view
    let toView = toViewController.view
    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    container.addSubview(toView!)

    // Replace your animations here
    toView?.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
    toView?.alpha = 0

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
      toView?.alpha = 1
      fromView?.alpha = 0

    }, completion: { finished in

      toView?.alpha = 1.0
      fromView?.alpha = 1
      fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
      transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Still works only on every other one. Can you show an animation example? Maybe I'm not animating correctly

Comment: Sure .. Check the edited answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Something in there fixed it. Thanks!